# Why does the creation date of a folder stay the same after that folder is deleted and re-created in the same location?

Tags: windows-7

This was tested on Windows 7; I haven't yet had chance to test on Windows 10.

1. Create a folder anywhere on the drive; for the purposes of this test, we'll call it "TestDir"
2. Wait several minutes, and take note of the "Date Created" attribute of the folder; once noted, delete the directory
3. Immediately, create a new folder in the exact same location and using the same name as the just-deleted directory
4. Take a look at the "Date Created" attribute of the just-created folder; you'll notice that it's the same as the folder that was deleted before it

Why does this happen - is there any particular reason for the above behaviour?

Comment: Interesting observation. This doesn't happen on Windows 10 by the way. I just tried it.

Comment: What happens if you press F5 after completing the steps above?

Comment: Define "deleted" and how you did it.

Comment: Deletion was performed in Windows Explorer by highlighting the folder, hitting Shift + Delete and confirming the deletion. Hitting F5 (or even closing the folder window) still results in the above happening when the folder is re-created.